# Cannot get Jackson XmlMapper to serialize pojo to xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm trying to use Jackson XmlMapper to convert a POJO to xml. I've used this library for json in the past, but the problem is that it's not working for xml atm. Can someone help me with why this might be happening? I'm new to this.

```
public class Pojo {

    public int x = 0;
}
```

---

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Serialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Pojo());
        System.out.println(xml);
    }

}
```

---

The error I get is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/ri/Stax2WriterAdapter
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.<init>(ToXmlGenerator.java:179)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:461)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219)
    at asd.Serialization.main(Serialization.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2WriterAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: This "works for me". What output are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The problem is that I get no output at all. I just updated the question with the error message.

Comment: What error message?

Comment: It's in the question.

Comment: What are you using for dependency management? It looks like you're missing the [stax2 libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core) that jackson uses.

Comment: That might be the problem because I'm not really sure what you're talking about. How do you actually add that?

Comment: When using a build tool like maven or gradle you declare a dependency on the version of the library you're using (in your case [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml)), then the tool will download the library _and all the libraries that it depends on_.